# Timer shows 010:00 after 10 minutes instead of 10:00

Tags: java, android, timer

What do I have to change so that the timer is showing 10:00 after 10 minutes instead of 010:00. I know a bit how to solve it but it doesn't solve the original problem -- if delete the "0" from `(textTimer.setText("0" + minutes + ":")` it shows `0:00` when its under 10. How do I make it to show 10:00 after 10 minutes and 00:00 before 10 mins. Thanks

```
    public void run() {
        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

        int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
        textTimer.setText("0" + minutes + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", seconds));
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
```

Comment: You do understand what `String.format("%02d",` is doing, right?

Comment: To answer your quesiton, you see this behavior because you are telling the computer to do so with `"0" + minutes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you're not formatting the entire string

```
textTimer.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
```